# How do I Permanently Delete a Huge Number of Emails in Outlook 2013?

Tags: freeze, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook, I have a folder that receives automated emails from some jobs.  I get a lot of these; sometimes several per minute.  I have emails like this going back at least a year in this folder, over 200,000 emails in total.  I'd like to delete everything in this folder.  When I try this, Outlook freezes and I have to restart it.  Here's what I tried:

1. Click on folder
2. Select All (Ctrl+A)
3. Freeze

I also tried this a different way:

1. Click on folder
2. Collapse Today, Yesterday, Sunday, Last Week, Two Weeks Ago, Three Weeks Ago, and Last Month.
3. Click on "Older"
4. Shift+Delete
5. Freeze

How can I delete all of the emails permanently?  And after that, do I need to compact some file somewhere?  I'm not an Outlook superuser, but I [read here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions/90920#90920) that this is the best place to ask MS Office questions.  I'm using Outlook 2013.

Comment: Are you sure it was frozen? Having that many emails to delete, it will take a while and Outlook may become unresponsive? How long did you wait?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried the second method over a long weekend.  I started it on Wednesday evening and then when I came in on Monday, Outlook was still frozen.  It can't take that long.  Can it?

Comment: Not likely. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't click on a folder. Start Outlook, *right-click* the folder, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select *Delete All*. After that you can compact PST (if you're using PST data file).